# How to unzip file via terminal in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, terminal, unzip, nstask

I want to unzip the file via terminal on Mac instead of using ZipArchive or SSZipArchive.

In terminal, I tried "unzip" command and it works good, but I do not how to express via objective c code.

I've tried this way (link: [Unzip without prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499110/unzip-without-prompt)) It works but only unzipped half of my files instead of all the files.

Thanks !!

Comment: @TBlue I opened new topic here. Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried the `system()` function?

```
system("unzip -u -d [destination full path] [zip file full path]");
```

You'll need to construct an `NSString` with your full command (including the file paths), and turn it into a C string for the system command, something like this:

```
NSString *myCommandString = 
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"unzip -u -d %@ %@", destinationPath, zipPath];
system([myCommandString UTF8String]);
```

This won't return any of the command's output, so you'd be better off with the solution from the [Unzip without prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499110/unzip-without-prompt) question if you want details about how the operation went, but if your project doesn't need error-handling this should be fine.

Comment: You can do it without NSTask?  That's simpler.  You get my vote.

Comment: @YUFENG I don't know exactly why NSTask didn't work, perhaps the `unzip` utility had an error and couldn't continue halfway through? I'm glad that this solution worked for you :)

Answer (score 3):

See the following.  I've revised a bit.

```
- (void)unzipme {
    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    NSMutableString *command = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
    NSArray *args;
    [task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"];
    [command appendString:@"unzip "];
    [command appendString:[self convertShell:sourcePath];
    [command appendString:@" "];
    [command appendString:-d ];
    [command appendString:[self convertShell:[self exportPath]]];
    args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-c",command,nil]; // Line 10
    [task setArguments:args];
    NSPipe *pipe1;
    pipe1 = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe1];
    [task launch];
    [task waitUntilExit];
}

- (NSString *)convertShell: (NSString *)path {
    static NSString *chr92 = @"\\";
    NSMutableString *replace = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:chr92];
    [replace appendString:@" "];
    NSString *sPath = [self Replace:path :@" " :replace];
    return sPath;
}
```

convertShell converts the Objective-C path to Shell path. Moreover, according to the unzip Man Page, this command-line tool takes a switch (-d) to specify a directory where to unzip an archive. sourcePath is a source zip file to unzip. exportPath is a destination folder.  If you get an error, insert NSLog(@"%@",command); before Line 10 and show me what the command says.

Comment: It will be nice if you cast an upvote for my effort.  Thanks.